# Is using a 4 inch - 5/8 hinge where a 4 inch 1/4 hinge used to go... doable?

Tags: hinges

I have a door with 3 hinges that are 4 inches - 1/4 inch radius on the corners. Finding a specific hinge with the same hole pattern seems to be impossible to find or extremely expensive.

Is there any issue with using a 4 inch 5/8 radius radius instead? Obviously it would fit. But the reverse would situation would not fit.

Why exactly are their 2 or 3 different sizes corner radius's? Is it a structural thing or simply esthetics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hinges all used to have square corners,  the rounded corners are to allow machines to cut the recess for the hinge more easily.  the corners are not structural.

[image: hinge with square corners]

If you are confident using a chisel replacing your rounded hinges with square ones may be another option.

Comment: "the rounded corners are to allow machines to cut the recess for the hinge more easily" ??? Can you explain this a bit more or point me to somewhere with more information. I was guessing it was not structural, but wanted to be sure. Na, I don't want to use a chisel, hence the fact i'm going with the 5/8 option to avoid unneeded extra work.

Comment: a router is used to cut the recess, if factories it's an automated router.  when I worked in a door factory the hanging machine came from these guys: https://kvalinc.com/ they have video,

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech routers, by their nature, make rounded corners. It takes extra steps to use a straight edged chisel to square off the corner. In large-scale production, that extra step to square the corner requires additional time and tooling that adds noticabely to the cost of production. The rounded corners on the hinge leaves are there to match the rounded corners left by the tooling, nothing more, nothing less. If your new hinge's round-over fits within the frame's existing mortise, go with it - you'll lose nothing, structurally speaking.